# Convert python dict of lists to a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I would like to go from this:

```
my_dict = {'key1': ['cat', 'dog'], 'key2': ['horse']}
```

to this:

```
my_tuple = [('key1', 'cat'), ('key1', 'dog'), ('key2', 'horse')]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[(key, value) for key, lst in my_dict.items() for value in lst]
```

output:

```
[('key1', 'cat'), ('key1', 'dog'), ('key2', 'horse')]
```

Comment: @William this means you have some values **that are not lists**, which is not what your question shows. Please update ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following iterations to achieve the output:

```
my_dict = {'key1': ['cat', 'dog'], 'key2': ['horse']}
my_tuple = []
for val in my_dict:
    for key in my_dict[val]:
        tup = (val, key)
        my_tuple.append(tup)
print(my_tuple)
```

you will then get the following output:

```
[('key1', 'cat'), ('key1', 'dog'), ('key2', 'horse')]
```